# How to use cpp (c pre-processor) with include path

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I am writing a parser which operates on C/C++ source files. As 1st stage of parser I need to use some already available preprocessor, so that I can get away with directives such as `#define, #ifdef`.
For g++, the available tool is `'cpp'` (or `g++ -E ...`). I had 2 questions:

1. My parser is written in C++, so what could be the best way to run this 'cpp' on other C/C++ source files? Is it something like:

   ```
   system("cpp sourceFile.cpp parsed_sourceFile.cpp"); // just a pseudo code
   ```

   Or is there any better way?

   (I want to know only the possible ways by which I can perform a preprocessing on given files. Are these commands like `system()`, or `popen()` are standard way to do such thing?)
2. How can I take care of the non-standard included files inside the source files? I will not know of anything that at which place these user defined header files are stored.

Comment: Are you on Windows or *nix?  The Win32 API has some calls (like ShellExecute()).  I'm sure *nix has their own, but I don't know what they are.

Comment: No, I am using unix type of platform. Why I confused with system() is because, I read somewhere that system("PAUSE") is a bad and non-portable command. But now I think that, it's specific to "PAUSE" and not meant for system() in general.

Comment: It is non-portable because I don't believe that "pause" is universal to all systems.  It's also a security risk in some cases, because if someone replaces your system's "pause" with a rogue program of the same name, then every piece of code you've written with system("pause") becomes dangerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**system** is the most cross-platform way possible. But if your code is single-platform, you can have better control over the execution of subprograms by using platform's native API. Like ShellExecute in windows.

There are a variety of places non-standard include files can be located, such as in the same directory as the source script. Such directories are usually mentioned in the project and MAK file of the projects. You can open those files and look for extra include locations mentioned in them. But the easier ;) way is of course to ask the user himself where those include files are.

Comment: Thanks, I had some doubts for system(). Now it's clear. By the way, I want to design in generic way, so system() is better way.